# How to check DISPLAY=:0 exist from python?

Tags: python, bash, xorg, xserver

Command:

`ps e | grep -Po " DISPLAY=[\.0-9A-Za-z:]* " | sort -u`

Output:

`DISPLAY=:0`

How to check `DISPLAY=:0` exist from python?

While `DISPLAY=:0` exist, `import os; print(os.environ['DISPLAY'])` not.

```
python -c "import os; print(os.environ['DISPLAY'])"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

For some reason this outputs empty string:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getoutput('ps e | grep -Po " DISPLAY=[\\.0-9A-Za-z:]* " | sort -u')
```

Output:

```
''
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. Do you want the `python-script` to send the `bash-command` and just report  back the output of the command?

Comment: I prefer pure python way if it exist.

Comment: @mrgloom : The error message clearly says, that at least **in the python process** the environment variable `DISPLAY` is not defined. Try a `printenv DISPLAY` before doing your `python -c ...`. I'm sure the variable won't show up either.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['DISPLAY']
':0'
>>> print(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
:0
>>>
```

---

```
$ python -c "import os; print(os.environ['DISPLAY'])"
:0
$
```

Not a problem at all =)

Comment: what version of python do you have?

Comment: This should be portable way back to early 2.x; but of course only examines the environment of the Python script itself.

Comment: @BruceBecker tried in 2.7 and 3.6 -- both work fine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if any process is using DISPLAY:0

```py
import psutil


def GetListOfDisplays():
    displays=[]
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if('DISPLAY'  in proc.environ()):
                displays.append(proc.environ()['DISPLAY'].split(':')[1])
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return list(set(displays))

print( '0' in GetListOfDisplays())
```

If there is a process using DISPLAY=:0
prints 
'True'
else
'False'

Tested in Python 3.7.4

Note:
If you execute this script as a non admin user, say, guest.
Then it will not be able to see what DISPLAY the admin processes are using.
Running this as root will allow you to get information on any process regardless of user.

Also you'll need psutil installed

```
pip install psutil
```

[psutil - pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)